# Spring Scheduled should start immediate after application startup

Tags: spring-boot, scheduler

I have a requirement to add schedulers, which will run on a daily basis, but at the same time, I want to run the scheduler on the application startup. But the problem is schedular is not running immediately after application startup.

Comment: Is it the SpringBoot program?

Comment: @HaiZi yes its Springboot apllication

Answer (score 0):

You can implement the ApplicationRunner interface and execute your business logic in the run method

```java
@Component
public class TaskRun implements ApplicationRunner {
    
    @Override
    public void run(ApplicationArguments args) throws Exception {
        // do something
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I solved this by using a listener in the Application.java

```
@EventListener(ApplicationReadyEvent.class)
public void doSomethingOnceAppIsReady() {
    //Calling a schedular method
    mySchedular();
}
```